# Conceptual difference between textEncoding and messageEncoding

Tags: wcf

There are 2 settings on bindings in WCF related to encoding. Could someone please explain the conceptual difference between these 2 settings?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

MSDN states the following:

[TextEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbindingbase.textencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):  Gets or sets the character encoding that is used for the message text.

[MessageEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbindingbase.messageencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): Gets or sets whether MTOM or Text/XML is used to encode SOAP messages.

So the first one (`textEncoding`) refers to the encoding of the characters in the message, and the second one (`messageEncoding`) specifies whether the SOAP message is encoded as text or MTOM (Machine Transmission Optimization Mechanism).

`textEncoding` allows you to specify a specific character set encoding of the **text** of the SOAP message, independent of what `messageEncoding` is set to.  For `messageEncoding`, MTOM is used for " efficiently encoding binary XML elements within the context of a SOAP envelope", whereas Text is used for interoperability purposes.

The default for `textEncoding` is `UTF8Encoding` and the default for `messageEncoding` is `Text`.

Other listed options for `textEncoding` include:

- ASCIIEncoding
- UnicodeEncoding
- UTF32Encoding
- UTF7Encoding